# Save windows state

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11

In my country, electricity outages occur daily, and they happen unpredictably without any fixed schedule. This situation poses a challenge as I have several ongoing tasks on my Windows computer, and it takes a significant amount of time to restore everything after each power outage. Is there a way available that can automatically save the state of my Windows system every 30 minutes? This would greatly help me in efficiently resuming my work without wasting much time on restoration.

Comment: Sounds like time to invest in a UPS.